# Starting Maariv prayers before dawn and finishing after dawn

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim, maariv

If one accidentally fell asleep, and woke up quite late and then started Maariv prayers, and managed to get through the Shema and part of the Amidah before dawn, but finished the Amidah after dawn (according to myzmanim.com).

Are there sources that deal with this situation?

I've only found one that refers to being in a state of *oneis* but it doesn't clarify how to handle that situation.

Comment: I'm amazed you could determine that precisely when dawn was!

Comment: שו"ת רב פעלים חלק א אורח חיים סימן ה
  ועל כן כל היכא דידע שלא יגמור התפלה קודם שיעבור הזמן, אסור לו להתפלל, אלא ימתין עד אחר שיגיע זמן תפלת ערבית ויתפלל שתים, אם הוא היה אנוס בדבר זה

Comment: הקורא קריאת שמע של ערבית אחר שעלה עמוד השחר קודם הנץ החמה (פירוש יציאת החמה מענין הנצו הרמונים) לא יצא ידי חובתו אלא אם כן היה אנוס כגון שכור או חולה וכיוצא בהן ואנוס שקרא אז לא יאמר השכיבנו דכיון שעלה עמוד השחר אינו זמן שכיבה.

Comment: I think that following the Gemara berachot 8b, see Rasha there, it's permitted to pray after the henets because it's permitted to say kriat shema a little time before the henets and we.pray after shema. If you initiated the tefila before henets there is no problem because the Gemara didn't mention anything about the end of tefila. Some tsadikim pray many hours, as the rabbi of Amshinov

Comment: @kouty that's about shema. Shema is Deorayta and has its own rules. Tefilla ends at the time for the next tefilla (on the simple reading. A few acharonim argue)

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe, it's logical. But some rishonim, not rabenu Tam, I don't remember who, argue that regarding zman tefilat arvit of rabbi Yehuda, it's good even for kriat shema. I remember a shagat Arie who discussed about this. And I wanted to use this reasoning inversely from shema to tefila because their reasoning is based on the fact that is and 18 are said together